# How do you detect the CPU architecture type during run-time with GCC and inline asm?

Tags: c, gcc, cpu, detection, inline-assembly

I need to find the architecture type of a CPU. I do not have access to /proc/cpuinfo, as the machine is running syslinux. I know there is a way to do it with inline ASM, however I believe my syntax is incorrect as my variable iedx is not being set properly.

I'm drudging along with ASM, and by no means an expert. If anyone has any tips or can point me in the right direction, I would be much obliged.

```
static int is64Bit(void) {
    int iedx = 0;
    asm("mov %eax, 0x80000001");
    asm("cpuid");
    asm("mov %0, %%eax" : : "a" (iedx));
    if ((iedx) && (1 << 29))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're running 64-bit code, then you're running on a 64-bit processor. Easy.

Comment: Anon: If you're running 32-bit code, you could be running on something such as a x86-64 architecture, not just a 32-bit one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many bugs can you fit in so few lines ;)

Try

```
static int is64bit(void) {
        int iedx = 0;
        asm volatile ("movl $0x80000001, %%eax\n"
                "cpuid\n"
        : "=d"(iedx)
        : /* No Inputs */
        : "eax", "ebx", "ecx"
        );

        if(iedx & (1 << 29))
        {
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need ebx and edx clobbers for cpuid too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and \@Peeter: `"=d"` is the EDX output.  You can't clobber an output operand, that won't compile.

Comment: You can also use constraints to give it the EAX input, with the side benefit that it will compile with `-masm=intel`  https://godbolt.org/g/Ltsww1.  Or better, use an existing `cpuid` wrapper function from `cpuid.h`.  [How do I call "cpuid" in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14266772)